# Should I include authenticated user within URL scheme?

Tags: web-services, rest, url, hateoas

Given a web-service with logged-in users, and resources for each user. Should the URL scheme include the user-ID or should the association of a HTTP request to a user be done via a cookie or some other means. E.g.

1. `GET acme.com/{user-ID}/books/{book-ID}` all information included within URL
2. `GET acme.com/books/{book-ID}` user-ID must be obtained from session/cookie/header

I like 1. (fully specified URL), as

1. There's a single URL for every single resource
2. It allows authorized impersonation, e.g. for a properly authorized support user to access a users records when necessary.
3. Being fully self-describing, the URL can be emailed, bookmarked, etc

I can also see it has problems regarding security - all user-ID's are guessable. Therefore a proper, tested authorization scheme is required.

What is considered best-practice? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

it's up to your use cases.  One really nice side affect of having the user id there is that it makes http caching easier on a shared client with a shared cache.  There's the http varys header, but that doesn't work well when you pass authentication as a cookie.  It can make sharing of a URL tougher because any url a user has is only for them which is the point.  You can supplement this with a redirect concept such that if a user gets a url with someone's else's user id, the server can redirect/provide the requesting users version of the resource (possibly).

If you allow anonymous access the user id in the path can become a bit cumbersome/clunky.

Most important thing to keep in mind (since you tagged this as rest) is that the client should NEVER have to have a handle to the user id outside of it being part of some obtuse URL.  The service should always be providing the URL WITH the userid filled in for the user, this way clients don't need to concern themselves with having to fill in a userid or not and as your app matures and you decide having the user id or not having it was a mistake clients still function.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons you list for preferring `acme.com/{user-ID}/books` are all valid and should be reason enough for you to choose that URL schema.

I would keep the actual authenticated user information in the Authorization header if possible. Generally in REST I find in the long run it pays of to follow the conventions of the underlying (HTTP) protocol.

And yes, you need a way to determine that the **authorized user** has access to books belonging to the **URL user**.